# How do we compare MAPEs?

Tags: regression, time-series, metric, mape

if we have two models M1 and M2:
MAPE_{M1} = 100%
and
MAPE_{M2} = 70%$

Does that mean that M2 is better than M1? can we say that M2 is (100/70 -1)*100 = 43% better?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Certainly you can say that. You could also say that M2 is $1-\frac{\text{MAPE}_{M2}}{\text{MAPE}_{M1}}=30\%$ better. It depends on what the denominator of your percentage calculation of "better" is.

However, whether all this has a useful meaning is very doubtful. As is the entire notion of MAPE. It looks easy to interpret and compare (which it isn't, this impression is highly misleading), but I have never seen an actual business problem that would best be addressed by a forecast that minimized MAPE, rather than one that minimized MSE or a pinball loss.

You may want to take a look at [What are the shortcomings of the Mean Absolute Percentage Error (MAPE)?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/299712/1352)